# Android: How to set the image in this ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

How do i set the images in this layout?

[image: List Entry]

The ListView will contain 3 of the above entries, each image will be downloaded in an `AsyncTask` (See Below) and the text will be filled in by a String array of preset Strings eg

```
String[] values = {"string one", "string two", "String three"};
```

I want to be able to first set the String content values of all 3 entries using the adapter below, then have AsyncTasks running in the background downloading and setting the icons for each entry.

The Strings are more important than the icons so i dont want the user to have to wait for each icon to download before the string is set.

I have a ListView Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_8dp" >
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/loading"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image" >

    </ImageView>
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_8dp"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_15dp" >

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Which is in a Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:entries="@array/list_headlines">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ive been working with this custom adapter:

```
private class ArticleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;
    
        public ArticleAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_entry, values);
            this.context=context;
            this.values=values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry,parent,false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            
            tv.setText(values[position]);
            
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

LoadThumbnail AsyncTask:

```
protected class LoadThumbnail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private String url;
        private boolean loaded; //if loaded set the bitmap image to whats downloaded
        private Bitmap icon;
        private int iconIndex;
        
        public LoadThumbnail(int iconIndex, String url){
            loaded = false; 
            this.url = url; //url of the icon to download
            this.iconIndex=iconIndex; //Which icon in the listview were downloading
        }
        
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Download download = new Download(url); //My Download Class
            try {
                icon = download.downloadImage(); //Returns A Bitmap image
                loaded=true; //If no errors caught
            } catch (Exceptions e) {
                //Various Exception Handling Here
            } 
            return null;
        }

        
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
        
        
    }
```

Can you tell me which functions i have to adapt to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: PS i have researched how to set images and i could do it if i already had all my bitmaps, but i dont know how to do this with background downloads

Comment: So, one thing, you'd need to set the image view (probably based on the local image path), if the image is not found, leave it as a placeholder, else set the image to imageview. After each cycle of AsyncTask (that is downloading the images) just call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Hope this helps.

Comment: you should use imageDownloader class...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to download your images to some `Collection` and then for the list to update when the downloads are complete by calling `notifyDatasetChanged` on the `Adapter`.

Before we get started - I don't know where your `AsyncTask` is located. If its a separate class you need to use an `Interface` to set up a call back to the place you're starting it from. If its an inner class within your `Adaper` you can do this localy.

What you're going to do is set up your `Adapter` to  (1) check if the image you want is available (2) if not download the image and add it to a collection (3) when the image is downloaded refresh the list (or when all images are downloaded depening how long this list is).

This all happens when you set the content for a specific list item

```
if(logo != null){
    if(imageCollection.contains(key){
        logo.setImageBitmap(imageCollection.get(key));
    } else {
        thumbnailDownloader.execute;
    }
}
```

If you're `AsyncTask` is an inner class witin your adapater then within `onPostExecute` you will (1) add the image to this collection (2) update the `ListView` using `notifyDatasetChanged`. If your `AsyncTask` is it's own class you would add the image to the collction in your callback and update the list from there as well.

For the `collection` it's easier if you use the `LruCache` built into android but you could use a `HashMap` or something else. Just depending on your implementation.

Comment: The asyncTask is a sub class of my ListFragment class to may things easy, so it can access any data the Adapter can

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd suggest to give a reference of the `ArticleAdapter` to the `AsyncTask`.
 
Then create a `Bitmap` array or map in `ArticleAdapter`, and create an `add(Bitmap bmp)` method for the ArticleAdapter, which puts a bitmap object into the array/map.
Because you have reference in the `AsyncTask`, you can call the add() method in the **`onPostExecute()`** method, with the downloaded icon `Bitma`p.
Then you can call the `ArticleAdapter`'s `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so it can refresh its views.
Of course your Adapter's `getView` should check its bitmap array/map, if the bitmap for the given key  is already downloaded. if it's reference is null, then put a placeholder, if it is downloaded already, place the bitmap which is put in the array/map by the asynctask.

Comment: How do i notifyDataSetChanged() surely it has to be (some object).notifyDataSetChanged() im working in a ListFragment if that helps and havent created an adapter object i can reference, i set the adapter by setListAdapter(new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), strings, icons));

Answer (score 1):

In getView(), you should start a new task to download the image for that list item. Pass a reference of the ImageView you want populated to the AsyncTask, and then set the source for that ImageView to the downloaded bitmap (icon) in onPostExecute().

This does get a little complicated as you will have to deal with Views being recycled by the ListView (by cancelling the tasks to download the images). I like to use this library for all my downloading and caching of images: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late but may be helpful for others.

In your code, if your `AsyncTask<>` is located as separate class then you can simply instantiate it with giving it `ImageView` in you adapter class, like

```
new LoadThumbnail(imageView).execute(url);
```

then in your `LoadThumbnail` class simply set bitmap in `imageView`.

i am writing this roughly, please make it as you want;

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry,parent,false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    tv.setText(values[position]);

    //Instantiate LoadThumbnail giving it imageView to set bitmap in.
    new LoadThumbnail(imageView).execute(url);

    return rowView;
}
```

Now in `LoadThumbnail` simply set bitmap in `onPostExecute()` method.

```
protected class LoadThumbnail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView imageView;

        public LoadThumbnail(ImageView imageView){
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            Bitmap icon = null;
            Download download = new Download(url[0]); //My Download Class
            try {
                icon = download.downloadImage(); //Returns A Bitmap image
                loaded=true; //If no errors caught
            } catch (Exceptions e) {
                //Various Exception Handling Here
            } 
            return icon;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap icon) {
            super.onPostExecute(icon);

            //here set bitmap in imageView;
            if(icon != null){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(icon);
            }
        }
    }
```