# Android: ArrayAdapter isnt setting images properly

Tags: android, image, listview, bitmap

Inside a ListFragment I have a ListView which contains an image and some text (See [Previous Solved Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466175/android-how-to-set-the-image-in-this-listview))

I briefly managed to get the solution to that question to work but its stopped working now.
I'm loading image Bitmaps in an `AsyncTask` which update the Adapter via `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

when they finish downloading I store the Bitmap in an class member: Bitmap array named `ICONS[]` which I access directly from the ArrayAdapter to save memory.

There's various checks in place to make sure i'm not downloading images multiple times all of which are working but ill add them here anyway:

note `i` here is each entry in the ListView

`ICONS[i] = null` for all `i` until they are downloaded and `ICONS[i]` becomes a Bitmap image.

`iconSet[i] = false` for all `i` until image is downloaded and set (updated within adapter), this stops the resetting of the `ImageView Bitmap` if its already been set.

`iconDownloading[i] = false` for all `i` until the `AsyncTask` downloader starts

`iconDownloaded[i] = false` for all `i` until the AsyncTask downloader finishes

```
private class ArticleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;
        public ArticleAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_entry, values);
            this.context=context;
            this.values=values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry,parent,false);
            
            TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            tv.setText(values[position]);
            
            if(ICONS[position]!=null&&!iconSet[position]){//not null and not set
                iconSet[position]=true;
                System.out.println("ArticleListFragment: Page " + pageIndex + " Setting icon " + position);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
                iv.setImageBitmap(ICONS[position]);
                
            }else if(!iconDownloading[position]&&!iconDownloaded[position]){
                iconDownloading[position]=true;//Starting download
                String iconUrl = ARTICLE_LIST.getArticle(position).getThumbnail();
                if(iconUrl!=null&&!iconUrl.equals("")){
                    System.out.println("ArticleListFragment: Page " + pageIndex + " Downloading icon " + position);
                    new LoadThumbnail(position, iconUrl).execute();
                }else{
                    System.out.println("ArticleFragment: Article " + position + " has no icon");
                }
                
            }
            //iv.setImageResource(resId);//Change Image - All set to sport at the moment
            
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

I've added a few System.out calls aswell to check everything is been done in the correct order, as intended the:

```
System.out.println("ArticleListFragment: Page " + pageIndex + " Downloading icon " + position);
```

Comes first then the:

```
System.out.println("ArticleListFragment: Page " + pageIndex + " Setting icon " + position);
```

Which is right before the setting of the Bitmaps, so its getting to the right point, with the right Bitmap (i assume as i've used `ICONS[position].size()` which outputs about 4000 bytes) so i'm stuck wondering what's going wrong?

**EDIT**
Ive narrowed the problem down to the check `if(!iconSet[position])` if i remove this the bitmaps are loaded correctly, but they are reloaded every time another bitmap is added to the ICONS array which for some reason triggers that `if` statement 4 times for 2 icons.

Why is it doing it 4 times? (twice per row entry) and why does that check make a difference?

Comment: It's not clear what's the problem. Also, you may want to check one of the libraries built for this scenarios(like the universal image loader) instead of your array based approach.

Comment: Ive narrowed down the problem being to the !iconSet[position] in the IF statement. Removing this loads the bitmaps, leaving it in still allows the statement to run but doesnt actually load the Bitmaps, even though the ICON[i] contains an icon...